# Query taking longer time to execute

Tags: oracle, subquery

Is there any method to reduce the time taken to get the result from below query?
Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
select status, count(distinct id)
from emp
where id >=
      ( select min(id)
        from emp
        where id >= (select max(id-200000) from emp)
           and trunc(join_date) >= '01-Mar-2018')
group by status;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Schema, indexes, explain plan - these are a bit necessary

Comment: Is id a primary key? If not, does it have an index anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Use analytic functions - this will perform only a single table scan (whereas your query has three table/index scans):

```
SELECT status,
       COUNT( DISTINCT id )
FROM   (
  SELECT status,
         id,
         MIN( CASE WHEN join_date >= DATE '2018-03-01' THEN id END ) OVER () AS min_id
  FROM   (
    SELECT status,
           id,
           join_date,
           MAX( id ) OVER () AS max_id
    FROM   emp
  )
  WHERE  id >= max_id - 20000
)
WHERE  id >= min_id
GROUP BY status;
```

Also, you can use a date literal (rather than relying on implicit conversion of a string to a date using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter) and you do not need to use the `TRUNC()` function (since that may prevent Oracle using an index on the `join_date` column and would instead require a function-based index).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know if id is a primary key (as columns with that name usually are) or not. If it is not, you definitely need an index on id for it to perform (and I would also wonder what the purpose of the column was). If id is the primary key, you don't need to the `distinct` as the values will be unique anyway.

The `select min(id)` sub-select is redundant as you already found max(id - 200000) so you don't need to know the first min(id) greater than that. You can just use >= by itself (with the condition on the date added). By the way, I would write `max(id) - 200000` instead; on some databases, it might work better.

The date comparison may be problematic. You should try an index on `join_date` if you haven't got one already, but the `trunc` might stop that from being used, so it would be best to remove that and make the other side of the compare use a `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `TO_DATE` to generate a corresponding literal as appropriate, setting the time to midnight.

But there can be problems with comparing timestamps due to timezones, etc. I'd need to know more about your setup to know whether that is likely to be a problem.

Comment: If `id` is generated in sequential order of `join_date` then `min(id)` might be redundant (the OP would need to confirm this) but if the `id` and `join_date` are not in sequence then the `min(id)` sub-query is not redundant as you can get `id`s with an earlier `join_date` than the filter that are still between the `min` and `max - 20000`.

Comment: Also, why did you include the section on timestamps? The OP is not using them and could just use a date literal. Also, there is no need to mention time zones since the OP isn't using them and the [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) function you referenced  generates a `TIMESTAMP` data type not a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (that is what the [`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm) function does).

Comment: I think that is solved by including the date where condition into the sub-query that selects the max id (I mis-read the brackets there).

Comment: re timestamps: it isn't clear what the type of join_date is. It could be a timestamp, in which case it is better to compare it with a timestamp (I should make that clear). There isn't enough to go on in the question to know what is best approach.